# How to reshape array inside an astropy.coordinate.SkyCoord object?

Tags: python, astropy

I want to make a 2D contour plot using **one** `SkyCoord` object **containing an array** of coordinates as an input parameter.

To do this, I wanted to make a mesh gird over parameters.

The code is something like this.

```
l = np.linspace(0, 360, 180)
b = np.linspace(-90, 90, 90) # Two axes I wanted to make contour on.
y=y.reshape(y.size,1,1) #(originally) an 1D array the same size as `coords`.
l=l.reshape(1,l.size,1)
b=b.reshape(1,1,b.size)
coords = coords.reshape(y.shape) # No, this does not work.
coords.shape = y.shape # You can't write attributes like this. How frustrating.
z = Something_Fun((l,b),y,coords)
```

The problem comes here.
I tried to use `np.meshgird` over `coords`, but it returns a **`np.array`** of `SkyCoord`, rather than **one** `SkyCoord` object **containing** an array of coordinates, which is not what I want. For the function `Something_Fun` calls member functions of `SkyCoord`, which certainly does not work with a `np.array`.

Unfortunately, a built-in `reshape` method is **not provided** for `SkyCoord`, even though it **does** have a `shape` method! If keep the shape of `coords`, the code won't work because operations cannot broadcast with arrays of different dimensions.

Is there any elegant way to do this? I do not wish to rewrite codes that generates `coords` or the function `Something_Fun` because it would mess up many other things.

Exporting `SkyCoord` data to string and import again might do the trick, but is much too "dirty" and loses precision. I might try it as a last resort.

Comment: `coords = np.reshape(coords, y.shape)`.

Comment: Support for reshape and other shape-changing methods is in work for coordinates at this time: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/pull/4123.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've come up with an solution on my own. It still involves exporting and import back and forth, but it would not lose precision. And it just works.

```
coords=SkyCoord(coords.ra.reshape(y.shape),coords.dec.reshape(y.shape))
```

Wish they would provide an built-in `reshape` method in the future, which would save me some time~